# how to query/setting variable in one python process form another python process?

Tags: python, process, ipc

Python snippet A :

```
import time

class task:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.progress_percent = 0

    def working(self):
        self.progress_percent = self.progress_percent + 1    
task1 = task()
task2 = task()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    task1.working()
    task2.working()    
    print task1.progress_percent
    print task2.progress_percent
```

How to query or even setting `task1.progress_percent` or `task2.progress_percent` runtime from another individual python process? (not pdb)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiprocessing.Process and Condition to do that. Please, try this code:

```
import multiprocessing

import time

class Task(multiprocessing.Process):
    counter = 0
    name = None
    event = None
    another_tasks = set()
    def __init__(self, mgr_dict, cond): 
        super(Task, self).__init__()
        self.mgr_dict = mgr_dict
        self.cond = cond
        cls = self.__class__
        cls.counter += 1
        self.name = '{} {}'.format(cls.__name__, cls.counter)
        self.mgr_dict[self.name] = 0

    def value(self):
        return self.mgr_dict[self.name]

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self.cond:
                self.cond.wait()
                self.mgr_dict[self.name] += 1

class SubTask(Task):
    pass

class MainTask(Task):
    subtasks = set()
    def working(self):
        with self.cond:
            self.cond.notify_all()

    def start(self):
        super(MainTask, self).start()
        for subtask in self.subtasks:
            subtask.start()

    def create_subtask(self):
        subtask = SubTask(self.mgr_dict, condition)
        self.subtasks.add(subtask)

    def join(self):
        self.mgr_dict[self.name]

    def shutdown(self):
        self.exit.set()

event = multiprocessing.Event()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    mgr_dict = mgr.dict()

    condition = multiprocessing.Condition()
    task1 = MainTask(mgr_dict, condition)
    subtask1 = task1.create_subtask()
    subtask2 = task1.create_subtask()
    subtask3 = task1.create_subtask()
    subtask4 = task1.create_subtask()
    subtask5 = task1.create_subtask()
    task1.start()
    while task1.value() < 100:
        time.sleep(1)
        task1.working()
        print mgr_dict
```

The result:

```
{'MainTask 1': 0, 'SubTask 1': 0, 'SubTask 2': 0, 'SubTask 3': 0, 'SubTask 4': 0, 'SubTask 5': 0}
{'MainTask 1': 1, 'SubTask 1': 1, 'SubTask 2': 1, 'SubTask 3': 1, 'SubTask 4': 1, 'SubTask 5': 1}
.
.
.
{'MainTask 1': 100, 'SubTask 1': 100, 'SubTask 2': 100, 'SubTask 3': 100, 'SubTask 4': 100, 'SubTask 5': 100}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however what I want to know whether I can query  task.progress_percent from another individual "python process", sort of "IPC" between processes

Comment: Ops.. Sorry =) 
You can do that with Shared Namespaces. I can make a example if you want.

Comment: appreciated if you can show an example, more, can 'Shared Namespaces' working for the different python process not spawned by progress A?

Comment: You should have main process. But all progress can be inside Process. Just a moment, I'm going to finish the example =)

Comment: thank you. And I find module 'rpyc' or 'pyro' can be useful to handle both RPC  and IPC access problem.

Comment: Nice lib (rpyc)! You can try Socket to IPC (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#socket-creation) also.